# Matching loss function for tanh units in a neural net

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

There's not much more I can add to the question.  Googling has mostly turned up research papers on springerlink and other sites I don't have access to.

Given a neural network model with $tanh(x)$ as the output non-linearity, what is the appropriate matching loss function to use?

-Brian

Comment: moving your comment above to an answer post, then accepting your own answer would certainly not offend this Site's guidelines or etiquette (One of the two S/E founders actually wrote a post on the S/E blog to encourage this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've derived something that'll work:

$$-\frac{1}{2}((1-x_0)log|1-tanh(x)| + (1+x_0)log|1+tanh(x)|)$$

The derivative of this quantity w/respect to $x$ is $tanh(x) - x_0$, which is precisely what I need.

Comment: This helps. I dont' think you need to take absolute value since tanh(x) is in (-1, 1).  By the way, this seems to be equivalent to the cross entropy loss after appropriate transformation.  So when implementing with neural network library, it would be easy to use sigmoid activation + cross entropy loss, with transformation of the target.

Comment: it's known that there is a strict relation between sigmoid and tanh (something like sigmx = 2tanh2x-1 or something like this)... so probably with a (tanhx + 1) / 2 you can get nice "probability like" values, IMO

Comment: 13 years later: I really wish I had outlined how I derived this.

Answer (score 3):

The loss function is chosen according to the noise process assumed to contaminate the data, not the output layer activation function.  The purpose of the output layer activation function is to apply whatever constraints ought to apply on the output of the model.  There is a correspondance between loss function and activation function that can simplify the implementation of the model, but that is pretty much the only real benefit (c.f. link functions in Generalised Linear Models) as neural net people generally don't go in much for analysis of parameters etc.  Note the tanh function is a scaled and translated version of the logistic sigmoidal function, so a modified logistic loss with recoded targets might be a good match from that perspective.

Comment: In this particular case, choosing a loss function that matches in the sense I'm referring to induces shortcuts in the arithmetic, and that's what I'm going for.  I understand that it isn't the most appropriate way to approach the problem from a statistical perspective, but it's what I need right now.

Comment: I think tanh(x) = 2/(1+exp(-2x)) - 1, so it is a scaled version of the logsitic sigmoidal function, so I suspect if you use a logistic loss function (cross-entropy) but with targets of +/-1, I suspect the same shortcut will apply.